# UIPopover is displayed briefly after app kill and resume

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover

I am trying to apply state preservation & restoration in an iPad app but if a popover is open then, during restoration, it is briefly displayed and then hides. This is caused by execution of code in `viewDidLoad` of the main view controller where the popover is attached to. This code takes some time to execute and it loads an html file in a web view. As a result when the web view finally loads the html file, popover disappears. Can I prevent the popover from hiding without moving the `viewDidLoad` code elsewhere?

Looking forward for your help!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    [webview loadHTMLString:text baseURL:baseURL];

}
```

This is the code that is run as a result of clicking on a bar button item.
However the problem appears when the app resumes with the popover previously left open.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"filterPopover"]) {

        if (self.filterPopover == nil && self.prefsPopover == nil) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"prefsPopover"]) {

        if (self.prefsPopover == nil && self.filterPopover == nil) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"filterPopover"]) {
        // Assign popover instance so we can dismiss it later
        self.filterPopover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        // assign delegate for popover dismiss purpose
        self.filterPopover.delegate = self;
        filterPopOverVisible = true;
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"prefsPopover"]) {
        // Assign popover instance so we can dismiss it later
        self.prefsPopover = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        // assign delegate for popover dismiss purpose
        self.prefsPopover.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. What causes the popover to  appear and disappear? There's nothing in the code you show that has anything to do with a popover.